# Como alterar uma View do SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho algumas Views no SQl Server que foram implementadas por outras pessoas ,mas as mesmas não deixaram nenhuma documentação e nem os scripts,acredito que seja possível acessar para alterar e dar manutenção nas mesmas? Mas não sei como fazer isso. 
Obs: A view vai ser acionada por um usuário no Excel!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize como exemplo a query abaixo.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VIEW_EXEMPLO]
AS
    SELECT 1
GO
```

Ou siga este passo a passo.

1. Clique com o botão direito na view;
2. Clique em **Script View as**
3. Clique em **ALTER To**

Comment: Valeu! Me perdendo com coisa básica!